# Laravel collection property staying the same in foreach

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Okay so here is my problem. I have code to get Walkaround records from the last 24 hours.
I then iterate over them in a foreach and for each Walkaround I iterate over it's `->questions` property and set a test property on each question, here is my code:

```php
$walkarounds = Walkaround::where('driver_id', $request->user()->id)->with(
    [
        'questionnaire' => function ($q) {
            $q->with(
                [
                    'questions'
                ]
            );
        }
    ]
)->get();

foreach ($walkarounds as $walkaround) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($walkaround->questionnaire->questions as $question) {
        Log::info($walkaround->id);
        $question->test = $walkaround->id;
    }
}

return $walkarounds;
```

The problem is that in my `laravel.log`, the correct **$walkaround->id** is being logged like so:

```
> [2020-03-04 13:28:37] development.INFO: [WalkaroundsController@index -
> L:50] 20   [2020-03-04 13:28:37] development.INFO:
> [WalkaroundsController@index - L:50] 20   [2020-03-04 13:28:37]
> development.INFO: [WalkaroundsController@index - L:50] 20  
> [2020-03-04 13:28:37] development.INFO: [WalkaroundsController@index -
> L:50] 21   [2020-03-04 13:28:37] development.INFO:
> [WalkaroundsController@index - L:50] 21   [2020-03-04 13:28:37]
> development.INFO: [WalkaroundsController@index - L:50] 21  
> [2020-03-04 13:28:37] development.INFO: [WalkaroundsController@index -
> L:50] 22   [2020-03-04 13:28:37] development.INFO:
> [WalkaroundsController@index - L:50] 22   [2020-03-04 13:28:37]
> development.INFO: [WalkaroundsController@index - L:50] 22  
> [2020-03-04 13:28:37] development.INFO: [WalkaroundsController@index -
> L:50] 23   [2020-03-04 13:28:37] development.INFO:
> [WalkaroundsController@index - L:50] 23   [2020-03-04 13:28:37]
> development.INFO: [WalkaroundsController@index - L:50] 23  
> [2020-03-04 13:28:37] development.INFO: [WalkaroundsController@index -
> L:50] 24   [2020-03-04 13:28:37] development.INFO:
> [WalkaroundsController@index - L:50] 24   [2020-03-04 13:28:37]
> development.INFO: [WalkaroundsController@index - L:50] 24  
> [2020-03-04 13:28:37] development.INFO: [WalkaroundsController@index -
> L:50] 25   [2020-03-04 13:28:37] development.INFO:
> [WalkaroundsController@index - L:50] 25   [2020-03-04 13:28:37]
> development.INFO: [WalkaroundsController@index - L:50] 26  
> [2020-03-04 13:28:37] development.INFO: [WalkaroundsController@index -
> L:50] 26   [2020-03-04 13:28:37] development.INFO:
> [WalkaroundsController@index - L:50] 26   [2020-03-04 13:28:37]
> development.INFO: [WalkaroundsController@index - L:50] 27  
> [2020-03-04 13:28:37] development.INFO: [WalkaroundsController@index -
> L:50] 27
```

However, in the returned `$walkarounds`, each `walkaround->questionnaire->questions->test` is the same value even though it is clearly logged as being different.

I am aware that this is a pointless use as I have scope of walkaround_id in each walkaround as 'id' already, I am actually trying to set a different property called `answer` that pulls a Answer record for the question and walkaround, my real usage was facing the same issue where I would get the answer for the right question but all the answers for all the walkarounds were the same because it seems whenever I use `$walkaround->id` outside of `Log::info`, in a `where()` or even in this case, just setting a test property, it makes all usages the same as what `$walkaround->id` is in the last loop iteration therefore even though all walkarounds had different answers, they all appeared the same.

This is extremely, extremely puzzling. When i was doing something like this:

```php
$question->answer = Answer::where('question_id', $q->id)->where('walkaround_id', $walkaround->id)->with('defects')->first();
```

I even logged out the sql being used and all the queries were being run with the correct walkaround_id

If I set up a test variable like `$i` and incremented for each walkaround and used that as the walkaround_id, it would work.

What is happening here? It's very strange.

> I have also tried this:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($walkarounds); $i++) {
    for ($n = 0; $n < count($walkarounds[$i]->questionnaire->questions); $n++) {
        $walkarounds[$i]->questionnaire->questions[$n]->test = $walkarounds[$i]->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: @CBroe You can alter laravel collections in a foreach, it does work like this. The same issues arrive when using the **->map()** function too

Comment: @CBroe For example, if I do $question->test = $i++, the test property in $walkarounds when I return it is incremented as expected

Comment: What happens when you change it to `$i = $walkaround->id;` outside the inner loop, and `$question->test = $i;` within?

Comment: @CBroe The same thing. **->test** on all questions in the id of the last walkaround in the foreach. I have tried ALOT of things, I have been scratching my head at this since last night because it doesn't make sense

Comment: Have you verified what $walkarounds contains right after the foreach loop? _Before_ it gets returned to elsewhere?

Comment: _“You can alter laravel collections in a foreach, it does work like this.”_ - does it also though, when you have two nested levels of this? Maybe `$walkaround->questionnaire->questions` gets correctly modified (can you verify _that_ outside of the inner foreach loop?), but this does not correctly “propagate” from there to the next level?

Comment: @CBroe print_r is showing the same as what is being returned. As for your most recent comment, I am about to update my question with another solution that I have tried

Comment: @CBroe Question updated

Comment: Using `for` loops and accessing the elements explicitly by index, should avoid any such issues. Can you please confirm again, that `$walkarounds` does not contain the expected thing _directly_ after that? Before it gets returned elsewhere.

Comment: @CBroe When i dump walkarounds before returning it, it has the same issue where ->test on all questions is equal to the id of the last walkaround returned by my ->get(). I have used similar logic before, I know that this should work.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything, I've decided to go for this solution that seems to work.
It involves casting the collection to an array:

```
$last24HrWalkarounds = Walkaround::where('driver_id', $request->user()->id)
    ->where('company_id', $company->id)
    ->where('started_at', '>', $formattedDate)
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->with(
        [
            'questionnaire' => function ($q) {
                $q->with(
                    [
                        'questions'
                    ]
                );
            }
        ]
    )
    ->get()->toArray();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($last24HrWalkarounds); $i++) {
    for ($n = 0; $n < count($last24HrWalkarounds[$i]['questionnaire']['questions']); $n++) {
        $last24HrWalkarounds[$i]['questionnaire']['questions'][$n]['answer'] = Answer::
        where('question_id', $last24HrWalkarounds[$i]['questionnaire']['questions'][$n]['id'])
            ->where('walkaround_id', $last24HrWalkarounds[$i]['id'])->first();
    }
}
```